# htaccess shorten URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/folder1/assets/Video/150/filename.mp4
```

I'm trying to shorten it like this

```
http://www.example.com/challenge/Video/150/filename.mp4
```

My current `.htaccess` implementation is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/challenge/Video$ /folder1/assets/Video [L]
```

But it's not working any assistance would help, I've tried other variations that I've seen but apparently, I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT 1)

To help give more insight: The user uploads a video to the server, and then the user is able to see/watch user submitted videos from the server. When the user submits the video the url is:

http://www.example.com/folder1/assets/Video/150/filename.mp4

When the user retrieves the video, I wanted them to get this URL http://www.example.com/challenge/Video/150/filename.mp4

to hide the actual file path/directory.

Edit 2)

I just added a picture from the results of the changes that @arkascha suggested, after fixing the PHP errors, i'm getting this when i change [END] to [L], when I use [END] I get a 500 error:

[image]

Edit 3) This is my full HTACCESS code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteCond /var/www/example.com/%1 -d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}  =""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/?challenge/Video/(\d+)/(.+)$ 
\/WebServices/assets/Video/$1/$2 [L]
```

When I removed everything above and just left the rewrite code you gave me it worked, but, i'm sure I may have needed to have some of these there. So if someone can help direct me to what line is causing it to act funny. I think it's the:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

but i'm not 100% sure. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *probably* is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?challenge/Video/(\d+)/(.+)$ /folder1/assets/Video/$1/$2 [END]
```

In case you encounter an "internal server error" (http status 500) using that rule chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. Have a try replacing the `[END]` flag with a `[L]` flag in that case. Your http servers error log file will have a specific for that issue.

The above internal rewriting rule will work in the http servers host configuration and likewise in dynamic configuration files (".htaccess" style files).

A general hint on that: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Alright so, I just put your rewrite rule in place of my code and I did get that http status 500 error, i'm looking into updating my apache (currently using Godaddy VPS) so that's an investigation of its own. Thanks so much for the help and taking the time to assist me. After I update the server, I will try your implementation again and see what happens.

Comment: When I changed [END] to [L] I got this: 

Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/example/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Comment: That is an issue with the PHP based logic you implemented, is has nothing to with apaches protocol layer where rewriting takes place. It appears that also that PHP code, probably some framework you use, is either very old or not well looked after. That warning has been uttered by PHP at least since PHP version 5.0...

Comment: And this indicates that your error visualization has to get reconfigured: currently error messages are displayed in the output, that makes little sense and is a no go for production code. Error messages belong into your http servers error log file which you need to monitor when using PHP in a web environment. So you need to change your PHP configuration accordingly.

Comment: Okay makes since, so after looking, into it I was able to resolve the PHP issues, however, If you look back at my original post, i've attached a screenshot of the error i'm getting now using [L] instead of [END] when I use end, I am getting that 500 error you were talking about in your initial answer. Any Idea as to what's going on here.

Comment: `[L]` will be just fine here, certainly no reason to upgrade the http server ;-)

Comment: Well, a http status 404 means exactly what it says: the requested object cannot be found on the server. Since this occurs one you introduce the rewriting and since we assume requesting the videos works without rewriting, the conclusion is that the rewriting is performed by the server, but the result does not target the correct location in the server object space. We cannot really help with that, since only you know your setup... But one possible reason here would be that the "old" URL of the videos got rewritten too, a step not applied any more with the new rule...

Comment: Dude, you are a life saver, so I was able to get it all working thank you so much, I really hope if there's other people that have issues this post would find them comfort hahaha. I did have to delete everything in my HTACCESS and just have that 1 line. If you don't mind, looking at EDIT 3: can you tell me what is causing that rewrite issue we discussed with the 404 so that I can remove that rule. hopefully without destroying any other API. Thanks So Much (marking as answered).

Comment: Looks like a question of the order of rewriting rules in that set of rules. They are processed top to bottom. Since the middle one routes all requests through the `index.php` script if the requested object does not exist in the physical file system you want to place this custom rewriting rule to the videos _above_ that general re-routing rule.

Comment: Nice that did the trick and everything on the app & website is still fully functional atleast everything i've tested so far ahaha, thanks again I'm actually an app front-end developer, but i'm making my first backend to my app & website so as you see i'm kind of lost in this backend space thanks for sharing your time with me and stepping throw all of my mistakes and helping me, much appreciated.

Comment: Hm, actually I would consider that part of the front-end ;-) Anyway, glad I could be of help. Take care and have fun!

Comment: Haha, well I mean I'm front-end App developer, I don't typically dwell in the web/SQL/backend stuff I normally just say what's the API for this or that call and params and I construct a restful json call to handle POST/GET responses etc. haha. Sorry for the confusion.